# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION when upgrading cxf 3.5.5 and spring 5.3.27

Tags: spring, cxf

Getting following error when ugrading Apache cxf from 3.4.4 to 3.5.5  and spring 5.2.22 to 5.3.27.

Searched stack overflow posts and most point to jaxb versions mismatch.  I have below jaxb versions:

**jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar**

**jaxb-impl-2.2.11**

**jaxb-api-2.2.11**

**jaxb-runtime-2.3.5/ jaxb-runtime-2.2.11 (tried both versions one by one by doesn't resolve error)**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:729)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:574)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:402)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:683)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:340)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:323)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:305)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
at com.adobe.idp.services.forms.FormsServiceService.getFormsService(FormsServiceService.java:72)
```

The RuntimeModeler is coming jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar

any pointers to troubleshoot the issue further ?

Comment: Looks like jaxws-rt is getting picked up instead of cxf jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `jaxws-rt` dependency resolved the issue.